# SSRS - Get group total within record scope

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Sorry if I don't explain this well - reporting services isn't my area of expertise. I believe this should be a simple one (hopefully).

I have a very simple report where I have a row group called 'group1' and then within that group I just have some records (which include a numeric field). Within the 'group1' header, I have put a sum of the numeric field record. What I am now wanting to do is calculate the percentage that each numeric field represents as a total of the group. So, for example, I currently have the following table.

```
-----------------------------------------
- GROUP 1                    100     
-----------------------------------------
- Field 1 | sadasaadasdads | 10 | 10% <== This is what I am trying to calculate
-----------------------------------------
- Field 2 | sadasaadasdads | 20 | 20%
-----------------------------------------
- Field 3 | sadasaadasdads | 50 | 50%
-----------------------------------------
- Field 4 | sadasaadasdads | 20 | 20%
-----------------------------------------
```

I am guessing I should be able to create an expression, however I need to know how to get the group total. Any help/guidance on how to calculate the percentage is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your dataset, this is what you are looking for:

```
select field1, field2, value, 
       100.0 * value / SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY 1) 
                      /* the SUM gets the total for the whole dataset. If actually 
                         have groups, yous should do PARTITION BY GroupField 
                       */
from yourtable
```

Now, you just have to work on the formatting.

Comment: +1 That's the right way to do it. Though why did you add the `OVER(PARTITION BY 1)`?, is there a performance gain over `OVER()` or was just for clarification?

Comment: You cannot just do SUM(value), since there's no grouping in the query. Partition by 1 will get the sum of all, that's it, 1 is 1 for all rows.

Comment: Oh, I know, I didn't expressed myself right. I meant, you could do the same query like this: `SUM(value) OVER()`, I just wanted to know if by adding `SUM(value) OVER(PARTITION BY 1)` had a performance gain or was just to make the query more understandable

Comment: Oh, OK. From a performance perspective, it will not matter. I chose to leave the `PARTITION BY` option for didactic purposes, showing OP there's an option if you have groups.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure whether SQL would be better than via reporting tools.

Comment: Calculations like group summaries are the strong part of reporting services and report tools in general. What would you write in SQL in case you wanted to SUM for each group in a report that contains 3 nested groups?

Comment: @niktrs Recursive CTEs! But I do agree some things should be kept in the app level